# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre usar ; y ,?

Tags: c++, c++11

**EDIT:** No se trata de una pregunta sobre el manejo de memoria dinámica, es una pregunta sobre el comportamiento del compilador cuando se separan las llamadas a funciones mediante coma. Este es un ejemplo de un libro para poner en manifiesto este comportamiento. Los destructores son llamados cuando se llega al final de la línea, en el ; , no cuando las variables salen de ámbito. Esto se puede comprobar mediante un cout en el destructor de la clase libro. Es decir, durante mostrar(l1), mostrar(l2), mostrar(l3) no se llama a ningún destructor, ni de las variables locales de las funciones ni de las del main, si no que todos son llamados una vez se ha terminado la ejecución de las tres funciones.

La pregunta es, por qué el compilador no llama a los destructores durante la ejecución de mostrar(l1), mostrar(l2), mostrar(l3), cuando las variables locales salen de ámbito (Comportamiento esperado), y en su lugar llama a todos los destructores cuando la ejecución llega al ;, es decir, cuando mostrar(l3) se ejecuta, aún no se ha llamado a ningún destructor, por eso al usar coma, la información sigue ahí cuando l3 quiere acceder.

En el siguiente ejemplo,

```
#include <iostream>    
#include <cstring>    
using namespace std;    

class Libro {    
 char* titulo_; int paginas_;    
 public:    
 Libro() : titulo_(new char[1]), paginas_(0) {*titulo_= 0;}    
 Libro(const char* t, int p) : paginas_(p) {    
  titulo_ = new char[strlen(t) + 1];    
  strcpy(titulo_, t);    
}    
 ~Libro() { delete[] titulo_; }    
 void paginas(int p) { paginas_ = p; }    
 int paginas() const { return paginas_; }    
 char* titulo() const { return titulo_; }    
};    

void mostrar(Libro l) {    
cout << l.titulo() << " tiene " << l.paginas() << " paginas" << endl;    
}    

int main() {    
 Libro l1("Fundamentos de C++", 474), l2("Por Fin: C ISO", 224), l3;    
 l3 = l1;    
 mostrar(l1), mostrar(l2), mostrar(l3);  
}
```

A pesar de que el constructor de copia no está implementado y el constructor generado por el compilador no funciona correctamente (Sólo copia la dirección al bloque de memoria de *titulo_*), al ejecutarse muestra correctamente la información en pantalla, con la función mostrar.
Sin embargo, al usar *;* en vez de *,*, el acceso a la memoria en la llamada mostrar(l3) es incorrecto, y no se muestra debidamente la información, puesto que cómo era de esperar, la copia no se ha realizado correctamente.
¿Sabéis cual es la diferencia entra usar *;* y *,*?

Comment: No, a la última,  mostrar(l1), mostrar(l2), mostrar(l3);

Comment: Ya encontré el fallo, no tiene nada que ver con el operador coma, edito mi respuesta.

Comment: @Trauma La pregunta es, por qué el compilador no llama a los destructores durante la ejecución de mostrar(l1), mostrar(l2), mostrar(l3), cuando las variables locales salen de ámbito (Comportamiento esperado), y en su lugar llama a todos los destructores cuando la ejecución llega al ;, es decir, cuando mostrar(l3) se ejecuta, aún no se ha llamado a ningún destructor, por eso al usar coma, la información sigue ahí cuando l3 quiere acceder. Siempre da error de doble liberación, puesto que se llama a los destructores cuando termina mostrar(l1),mostrar(l2),mostrar(l3); y al salir del main.

Comment: @jramirez se llama al destructor antes de lo que crees, edité mi respuesta. Se llama al destructor porque pasas el objeto por copia.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> ¿Sabéis cual es la diferencia entre `;` y `,`?

Si. Empezaré por la única similitud que tienen, ambos están recogidos en [el estándar](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) en el apartado 2.12 (traducción mía):

> #### 2.12 Operadores y puntuación
>
> 1. La representación léxica de los programas C++ incluye un número de elementos de pre-procesado que son usados en la sintaxis del pre-procesador o se convierten en elementos para operadores y puntuación:
>
> *pre-procesador-o-puntuación*: uno de los siguientes:
>
> ```
> {     }        [        ]       #       ##     (         )
> <:    :>       <%       %>      %:      %:%:   ;         :     ...
> new   delete   ?        ::      .       .*
> +     -        *        /       %       ˆ      &         |     ~
> !     =        <        >       +=      -=     *=        /=    %=
> ˆ=    &=       |=       <<      >>      >>=    <<=       ==    !=
> <=    >=       &&       ||      ++      --     ,        ->*    ->
> and   and_eq   bitand   bitor   compl   not    not_eq
> or    or_eq    xor      xor_eq
> ```

Ahora, las diferencias

## `;`

Es un símbolo de **puntuación**. Indica hasta que punto llega un elemento que deberá interpretar el compilador.

## `,`

Es un **operador** binario. Su comportamiento es evaluar el primer operando y descartar su resultado para acto seguido evaluar el segundo operando y devolver su valor. Por ejemplo, el siguiente código almacena `5` en la variable `i`:

```
int i = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

El operador coma (`,`) evalúa `1` y lo descarta, acto seguido evalúa `2` y lo descarta... así hasta evaluar `5` y devolverlo, el siguiente código almacena `6` en `j`:

```
int i = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
int j = (++i, i++);
```

El operador coma evalúa `++i` (que es `5` y pasa a ser `6`) y lo descarta, acto seguido evalúa `i++` (que dejará `i` con valor `7` pero devuelve `6`).

Estos ejemplos no son útiles, tan sólo ilustrativos, pero el operador coma se puede usar en otros contextos más útiles como en el bucle `for`:

```
for (int i = 0, d = 100; i < d; ++i, --d)
    // hacer cosas...
```

En el código anterior, el mismo bucle incrementa y decrementa las variables de control sin necesidad de *ensuciar* el cuerpo del bucle.

### Tu caso.

Estás usando el operador coma (`,`) en esta instrucción:

```
mostrar(l1), mostrar(l2), mostrar(l3);
```

Por otro lado, la función `mostrar` recibe un libro por copia:

```
void mostrar(Libro l)
// Copia! -> ^^^^^^^
```

Así que lo que sucede es:

1. Se llama a la función `mostrar` con el parámetro `l1`.

   - `l1` Se copia en el parámetro `l`.
   - Se muestra `l`.
   - **Se destruye `l`**, que al ser copia de `l1`, deja su puntero inservible.
   - Se descarta el resultado de `mostrar(l1)` (que no descarta nada porque la función no devuelve nada).
2. Se llama a la función `mostrar` con el parámetro `l2`.

   - `l2` Se copia en el parámetro `l`.
   - Se muestra `l`.
   - **Se destruye `l`**, que al ser copia de `l2`, deja su puntero inservible.
   - Se descarta el resultado de `mostrar(l2)` (que no descarta nada porque la función no devuelve nada).
3. Se llama a la función `mostrar` con el parámetro `l3`.

   - `l1` Se copia en el parámetro `l`.
   - Se muestra `l`, **pero es una copia de `l1`** que en estos momentos contiene un puntero inservible pues se borró en el paso 1.
   - **Se destruye `l`**, que al ser copia de `l3` que a su vez es copia de `l1` intenta borrar memoria que ya ha sido borrada y el programa causa corrupción de memoria.

Así que deberías recibir por referencia (constante) el `Libro` en la función `mostrar`:

```
//           vvvvv       v <--- Referencia constante
void mostrar(const Libro &l) {    
cout << l.titulo() << " tiene " << l.paginas() << " paginas" << endl;    
}
```

Además, como hemos podido ver, el operador coma no tiene nada que ver con tu problema. Lo que te está sucediendo es que liberas dos veces un puntero provocando una corrupción de memoria. Puedes solucionarlo implementando manualmente el operador de copia:

```
Libro &operator =const(const Libro &otro)
{
    delete []titulo_;
    titulo_ = new char[strlen(otro.titulo_) + 1];
    strcpy(titulo_, otro.titulo_);
    return *this;
}
```

### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

#### La regla de los cinco.

Cuando una clase maneja un recurso (en este caso: memoria), hay que tener mucho cuidado a la hora de gestionarlo, esto se conoce como "*La regla de los cinco*"<sup>1</sup> que a grandes rasgos dice que si implementas una de las cinco operaciones especiales (constructor, constructor de movimiento, destructor, operador de copia, operador de movimiento) es muy posible que tengas que implementar también el resto.

#### Manejas mal los recursos desde el principio.

Tu constructor por defecto pide memoria pero no la libera en caso de re-asignación:

```
Libro() : titulo_(new char[1]), paginas_(0) {*titulo_= 0;}   
//                ^^^^^^^^^^^ <--- Pedimos memoria.
~Libro() { delete[] titulo_; }
//         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <--- liberamos memoria
```

Si entre el constructor por defecto y el destructor ha habido una re-asignación del objeto, la memoria pedida en el constructor no se libera, es por eso (entre otras cosas) que necesitas implementar el operador de copia (como he sugerido).

#### No necesitas punteros.

C++ dispone de clases para gestionar cadenas de caracteres que liberan al programador de la responsabilidad de manejar manualmente la memoria, te sugiero que cambies tus punteros a caracteres por `std::string` haciendo mucho más sencilla la clase:

```
class Libro {    
    std::string titulo_; int paginas_ = 0;
public:
    Libro() = default;
    Libro(const char* t, int p) : titulo_{t}, paginas_{p} {}    
    void paginas(int p) { paginas_ = p; }
    int paginas() const { return paginas_; }
    const std::string &titulo() const { return titulo_; }    
};
```

Como puedes ver, dado que `std::string` maneja por su cuenta la memoria, no necesitas destructor (el destructor de `std::string` se hace cargo de su memoria) ni manejar memoria manualmente. Por otro lado, dado que desde C++11 se pueden inicializar los miembros en el mismo punto en que se crean puedes obviar el cuerpo del constructor por defecto y dejar que el compilador lo genere por ti (`Libro() = default;`)

---

<sup>1</sup>Que antes de C++11 era la regla de los tres.

Comment: Es un UB, con lo cuál no es determinístico... cambiar el programa aunque sea ligeramente puede dar resultados diferentes, ¡podrían hasta salirle demonios nasales!.

Comment: El estándar dice que los objetos deben ser destruidos (en orden inverso a su creación) al salir del ámbito de su creación; así pues, a no ser que sean un r-value (que `l1`, `l2` y `l3` no lo son) se destruirán al salir del programa (en la llave de cierre de `main`) no antes.

Comment: *Ergo* es imposible que falle. Osease, va a mostrar unos resultados correctos por pantalla **siempre**, seguidos por el opcional mensajito de error sobre la doble liberación.

Comment: En cuyo caso, la pregunta necesita una edición **profunda** ;-)

Comment: *Ergo* el programa se comporta erráticamente porque cae en UB, por eso ni entendí la pregunta al principio ni respondí bien al principio :)

Comment: Si se añade un cout en el destructor, se puede observar que no se llama a ningún destructor hasta que se llega al ;, es decir, durante mostrar(l1), mostrar(l2), mostrar(l3), no se llama a ningún destructor, si no que se llama a los tres destructores cuando se llega a ;, por eso puede acceder l3 a la información

Comment: @jramirez eso pasa porque *casualmente* es la última instrucción del programa (al que le falta el `return 0`, por cierto) haz operaciones adicionales después de `mostrar(l1), mostrar(l2), mostrar(l3);` (yo que se... un bucle, un *Hola mundo*, algo...) y observarás que el destructor no se llama hasta salir de la función, no en el momento de alcanzar el `;`. Mira de hecho [ya te lo enseño yo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/f51x4BNkBLlRV2RH) ;) y me has ayudado a detectar **OTRO** problema en el código del autor :P